# connect XML file to Label (objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, uilabel

I have an `UIViewController` page with one button and one **label** . I added xml parser on my project and everything works (I test it in console), right now I want to connect my XML file to my label to just get one attribute of XML file(for test). My question is how can I connect XML to my label. Would you please give me some hint for implementing this?

I'm new to objective-C

Here is my code:

I just want to see how we can connect xml file to label

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   //appDelegate = (testAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
   // label.text = aBook.title; //it not working, I don't know what should I write to get one   
   // element of xml file to this label or first element of xml file

   [super viewDidLoad];

 }
```

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Books>

<Book id="1">
    <title>
        Circumference</title>
    <author>Nicholas Nicastro</author>
    <summary>Eratosthenes and the Ancient Quest to Measure the Globe.</summary>
</Book>
<Book id="2">
    <title>Copernicus Secret</title>
    <author>Jack Repcheck</author>
    <summary>How the scientific revolution began</summary>
</Book>
<Book id="3">
    <title>Angels and Demons</title>
    <author>Dan Brown</author>
    <summary>Robert Langdon is summoned to a Swiss research facility to analyze a cryptic symbol
   seared into the chest of a murdered physicist.</summary>
</Book>
<Book id="4">
    <title>Keep the Aspidistra Flying</title>
    <author>George Orwell</author>
    <summary>A poignant and ultimately hopeful look at class and society, Keep the Aspidistra 
 Flying pays tribute to the stubborn virtues of ordinary people who keep the aspidistra
  flying.    
 </summary>
</Book>
```

and if it's needed here is my parser class:

```
- (Presentation1NameXML *) initXMLParser {

appDelegate = (testAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"]) {
    //Initialize the array.
    appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) {

    //Initialize the book.
    aBook = [[Presentation1Name alloc] init];

    //Extract the attribute here.
    aBook.bookID = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];

    NSLog(@"Reading id value :%i", aBook.bookID);
}

NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
 }

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

if(!currentElementValue)
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}   

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"])
    return;

//There is nothing to do if we encounter the Books element here.
//If we encounter the Book element howevere, we want to add the book object to the array
// and release the object.
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) {
    [appDelegate.books addObject:aBook];
    aBook = nil;
}
else
    [aBook setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
currentElementValue = nil;
}



@end
```

**Edit:**

when I used

```
 NSLog(@"%@", aBook.title); I got NULL
```

**Edit**

in some sample that I saw they have something like this also

```
 Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

since they use it in tableView But I don't have any table what should I write instead of 
    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: are you sure the [aBook setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName]; is working? and where do you read and parse the xml? in another viewController? how do you set the book for the viewController where you have the label?

Comment: @jcesar yes it's worekd , I pars xml in another viewController

Comment: Since you say that everything has worked (by that you mean parsing XML, I suppose) we can cross that off the list.  Next, is your application delegate actually accumulating the books?  Next, how does your view controller get the `PresentationName` object that you want it to display?  I don't see any code in `viewDidLoad` that references a `PresentationName` object a.k.a "book".

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   appDelegate = (testAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:0]; //This will load the first book
   label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
   label.text = aBook.title;   
   [super viewDidLoad];

 }
```

If you tell me more about how do you load the viewController with the button and the label I can give you a better answer.